# Azure : Why i can't ping SMPT server's domain from a VM?

Tags: azure, smtp, ping

I have a windows vm `VM1` with its vnet `VNET1`, and it is able to ping our SMTP server's domain. The configuration is done by another person (Not me)

I have a second Ubuntu vm `VM2` with its vnet `VNET2`, and it is NOT able to ping the SMTP server. i got

```
ping: xxxx-smtp.somedomain.net: Name or service not known
```

Is there a way to configure `VM2` with `VM1` to resolve `xxxx-smtp.somedomain.net` ?
PS: i tried using peering between `VNET1` and `VNET2`. But the problem still present

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment*** to configure `VM2` with `VM1` you can make use private DNS zone like below:

Created ***virtual machine:***

[image]

Created a ***private DNS zone:***

In private DNS zone -> under setting, Click virtual network links like below:

[image]

Now, Add a vnet1 and vnet 2 in the virtual network link like below:

[image]

[image]

Once your both vnet are added, vm1 is associated with DNS zone along with virtual network like below

[image]

you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837850/azure-how-do-i-associate-the-private-dns-zone-with-virtual-networks-across-the?rq=2) for more details